# Source Tree Unity project Ghost files

Tags: git, file, unity-game-engine, version-control, bitbucket

Recently changed my Gitignore which was fine until i pulled down on another machine to find some of the project was not there. So i have switched back to my old git ignore but now as soon as i open the project and go to source tree these files and folders need pushing every time.

[image]

I do not edit these files and every commit they come up.
Then even though i have hidden meta files selected in the settings whenever i make any change, it makes me commit a load of meta files.

Any ideas to fix both these issues.

Here is my git ignore.

```
# =============== #
# Unity generated #
# =============== #
[Tt]emp/
[Oo]bj/
[Bb]uild
[Ll]ibrary/
sysinfo.txt
*.stackdump

# ===================================== #
# Visual Studio / MonoDevelop generated #
# ===================================== #
[Ee]xported[Oo]bj/
.vs/
/*.userprefs
/*.csproj
/*.pidb
/*.suo
/*.sln*
/*.user
/*.unityproj
/*.booproj

# ============ #
# OS generated #
# ============ #
.DS_Store*
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
Icon?
ehthumbs.db
[Tt]humbs.db
```

Comment: Generally, many/most Unity teams use subversion.  Git is really not relevant for binary files, deleting folders etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a zillion-times duplicate question but,

1) git is for ***source*** control.  "source" means small text files (ASCII files), being computer languages.

**You don't use git, at all, for things like filmmaking, game production, in a music studio, the TV business, etc.**

The game industry generally runs on subversion.

(Unity projects have four or five tiny "source" files, and then gigabytes of video, animation, textures, models etc. It's just totally unsuitable for git.)

2) If for some reason you are trying to use git with a Unity project. FYI the usual suggestion,

## simply use the actual up-to-the-minute official plan FROM GIT THEMSELVES:

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore

Hooray!

You often see long-winded discussions about "how to use git with Unity", this is bizarre as (the best you can do with git) is right there, courtesy git [git](http://www.theverge.com/2014/4/28/5662174/github-apologizes-for-vagueness-reveals-new-details-about-sexism).

Just to repeat, do note that it is ***incredibly easier*** to use svn with Unity.  svn is made for media, film, game etc projects.  Git is really for *source* (i.e. computer code files). Unity projects have a few hundred bytes computer code ASCII files, and very often **100s of gigabytes** of music, video, texture, modelling etc assets. You're knocking yourself out using git for no reason.

Comment: I am just looking at your link quickly, i did manage to fix the issue, just going to give it a read before marking you answer as correct.

Comment: Just a FYI, Git has an extension specifically for [large file support](https://git-lfs.github.com/) and the extension is supported by both GitHub and [TFS in Git mode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/10/01/announcing-git-lfs-on-all-vso-git-repos/)