# Do I need to add all Unity and Xcode project files to git repo?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, unity-game-engine

I have a question related to Xcode and Unity projects. Today I managed to create a Xcode project from Unity and I wanted to add it to my git repo, but the size of the folder with project is over 900 MB. I don't have a lot of assets, and I'm using only UnityAds and GoogleAnalytics as plugins.

Do I need all of those files in my repo?

Does anyone have gitignore sample for Unity + Xcode settings?

Comment: just include [git ignore for xcode](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Objective-C.gitignore)

Comment: hi Gekon, this exact question is often asked.  note that (1) for film, tv, games, unity, music etc you use svn not git. (2) 900 mb is ***tiny*** for a games project!  (3) if for some reason you want to struggle with git, git themselves gives the best possible "recipe" on their web page.  hope it helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Source Tree Unity project Ghost files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35393928/source-tree-unity-project-ghost-files)

Comment: on top of all that, [git generally sucks](http://www.theverge.com/2014/4/28/5662174/github-apologizes-for-vagueness-reveals-new-details-about-sexism) and will suck worse once they sell out to someone or try to get listed, but that's another story I guess

Comment: also just a note Gekon.  why would you want to save the *Xcode project* generated by Unity?  just throw it out and build it each time - it's useless to keep it.  (except in extremely unusual situations.)  you really "shouldn't" keep it for any reason, it's (with only a few rare exceptions) "wrong" to do so.

Comment: @joe-blow - My core Unity project does not take more than 100MB. After your last answer I did some tests and you were right, I don't need to save XCode project, all stuff can be configured in Unity.

Comment: hi @Gekon.  right, as a rule you don't keep the generated Xcode project.  hope it helps cheers

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called .gitignore on the top level and add the folders you do not wish to commit to your GIT

ie.

```
bin/
UnityAds/ 
GoogleAnalytics/
```

Here is a good one I found:

```
/[Ll]ibrary/
/[Tt]emp/
/[Oo]bj/
/[Bb]uild/
/[Bb]uilds/
/Assets/AssetStoreTools*

# Autogenerated VS/MD solution and project files
ExportedObj/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd


# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta

# Unity3D Generated File On Crash Reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.unitypackage
```