# Unity projects collaborated on github not working properly

Tags: github, unity-game-engine

So when I am working on games using Unity, I collaborate the project with my team members over github. Everything works out fine with the c# code that we use. But when we are trying to build scenes, which will cause Unity to auto generate a bounch of files, these files sometimes cause problems. Some times these scenes work perfect on my computer but once shared to my friends, it crashes or cause numerous bugs.

I just want to know how professional Unity developers usually collaborate on game projects. Does git ignore help? Are we only supposed to collaborate the scripts and not the scenes? Thank you!

Comment: You may want to read this section of the manual; "[Using External Version Control Systems with Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html)", it may just have all the answers you need. Also see the section on [SmartMerge](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SmartMerge.html), specifically the section for using it with Git.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35395717/294884