# Sharing a Unity project - Private credentials risk

Tags: git, github, credentials

I need to upload an old project I made in Unity to github. However I made this app around three years ago and it was the last time I used Unity or uploaded anything to the Play Store and as such my knowledge of the subject is fairly rusty. I vaguely remember including some form of developer unique ID and possibly my password either in my code or in the Unity editor itself that relates to the my developer account with the Play Store/AdMob. My question is this....

If I upload all of my source code files to github will that confidential information be made public? And if so, which files must I be sure to omit.

Thanks

edit: It's a public github account

edit: I've just remembered that it was the Keystore name and password. I believe it was entered in to the Unity Publishing settings but I'm not sure where and how securely Unity stores that info  in source code.

So the question is rephrased to... If I upload all of my source files. Will my keystore information be safe?  Thanks again!

Comment: If it's a public repository, then yes it's public. If it's a private repository then it's private. You would need to exclude the files containing your credentials, and only you can determine which ones they are!

Comment: you don't (as a general rule) use "git" for film making, the game industry, music production and so on.  you use subversion.  (git is for literally "source code" - - ie, tiny ASCII  text files containing computer code.)  Unity projects have a minuscule amount of "source code" (like a few hundred bytes) and 100s of GB of music, animation, video etc.

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Comment: make a `config` file, add a wrapper for it, put all of your sensitive information in it and add it to your `gitignore`

Comment: AND do not push any password since if you do, believe me, removing them from git is like a nightmare

Comment: @JoeBlow can you please elaborate on why svn is better than git in handling big gaming projects?

Comment: **git is for literally "source code" - - ie, tiny ASCII text files containing computer code.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Source Tree Unity project Ghost files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35393928/source-tree-unity-project-ghost-files)