# Best way to perform version control on Unity projects

Tags: git, svn, unity-game-engine, version-control

I'm developing my first big Unity project. It is a game and I have a lot of assets (now they use over 200 Mbs of hard disk).

I would like to use a control version like GIT as I use in my android java projects, but when I have tried to use it it's taking to much time and gets frozen.

Do you know a good version control system for unity projects? I don't want to use gitignore to quit assets from control version as I'm doing now.

Many thanks,

Comment: gab, you mention "200mb".  I have never seen a Unity project that small !!  Just as you say, git is useless.  Use subversion for Unity projects, enjoy.  BTW sorry I slightly misread your question at first, cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For unity (and any game, film, music etc) project **pretty much everyone simply uses subversion**.

Git is for ***source*** control:

ie, when you have a *source* - i.e. software, i.e. a few tiny text files.

## Git is for computer code files - i.e Text Files of C, Java, or any other text file computer language.

Whereas ...

### Unity has almost no relationship to computer code files or indeed text files. It's more like making, say, a film or an enormous photoshop project.

(The entire raison d'etre of git is the "ability to work offline!" with computer code text files: that feature is utterly irrelevant to storing terabytes of textures, video, 3D models, enormous binary scene files, etc.)

It is trivial to get SVN repos, for example at **xp-dev.com** or any number of free or paid suppliers.

On your **Mac** the best subversion client is VersionsApp (unfortunately you have to pay for it). On your **PC**, everyone uses TortoiseSVN (free).

(Of course, on Mac you can just use the command line svn client, which is built-in to OSX since it's just unix.)

For games, video, modelling, 3D, film etc SVN is the industry standard.

Comment: I agree strongly that for large (over 5MB) binary files, Subversion is a far better solution then git.  For one thing, you can choose to only bring down part of a repository (sparse working copy), which means if the repository is 10-15GB, you don't have to bring it all down (just the folder that you care about).  It also stores deltas instead of full snapshots, plus is efficient across the wire for binary files.  The downside is that you must adopt the mantra of "update, modify, commit" in short cycles to avoid conflicts.

Comment: indeed.  you sometimes get "git v. svn" wars (which I could not care less about).  it's jus that in the Unity "industry" it's usually subversion.  If you engineer Unity for a living most large clients will be svn.