# How do I export whole Unity project with all scenes?

Tags: unity-game-engine, zip, export

I want to export my Unity project as a ZIP folder, but I can't. When I click on `Asset > Export Packages`, only one scene gets exported. I want to export the project so that I can send it.

Comment: Eh, what's wrong with just adding the entire project folder to a ZIP archive (or something similar)? (Just travel up the directory tree until you get to it.)

Comment: It's very large = 500MB

Comment: you can always use git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save your scene and project and close unity and simply copy the project folder or make an archive of that main project folder and copy it. (Closing Unity is an important step because all temporary files are deleted which were opened)

And about the file size, yes generally they are bigger if you have used high quality models or textures. You can try building it for a platform like Android or Windows etc. and send that executable build to somebody else (usually smaller file size).

P.S: Have tested it before and works like a charm.

Comment: Isn't the archive too large?

Answer (score 14):

You can zip the `Assets` folder and `ProjectSettings` folder and ignore all other files and directories.

You don't need Library and Obj folder. They get created automatically.

The project files (.csproj) and similar files also get created automatically.

Alternatively you can export the whole project as a package:

> Use Export Package to create your own Custom Package.
>
> 1. Open the project you want to export assets from.
> 2. Choose Assets > Export Package… from the menu to bring up the Exporting Package dialog box.
> 3. In the dialog box, select the assets you want to include in the package by clicking on the boxes so they are checked.
> 4. Leave the include dependencies box checked to auto-select any assets used by the ones you have selected.
> 5. Click on Export to bring up File Explorer (Windows) or Finder (Mac) and choose where you want to store your package file. Name and save the package anywhere you like.

Comment: In effect omit everything that you'd normally have in [the .gitignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225126/how-to-use-git-for-unity-source-control/18225479#18225479). But at that point, just creating a repo for this might be more convenient... =P

Comment: @Serlite across every unity project I have encountered so far only Assets and ProjectSettings contained the vital parts. however one may still reduce the size by ignoring as .gitignore does!

Answer (score 1):

For Unity 2017.2+ with package manager

- Save all your files
- Close Unity
- Make an archive that contains `Assets`, `Packages` and `ProjectSettings` folders

That's it, Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this need and got it done following a comment from [this post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-export-package-with-projectsettings.418148/).

We need to create a script inside an "Editor" folder so it does not affect the project building capabilities. Then we write the following code into it:

```
using UnityEditor;

public class ExportPackage
{
    [MenuItem("Exports/Export Project")]
    static void Export()
    {
        ExportPackageOptions options = ExportPackageOptions.Interactive |
            ExportPackageOptions.Recurse |
            ExportPackageOptions.IncludeDependencies |
            ExportPackageOptions.IncludeLibraryAssets;

        // Gets all the assets in the project
        string[] paths = AssetDatabase.GetAllAssetPaths();

        // Defines the name of the package file. It will be stored on the project's root folder.
        string fileName = PlayerSettings.productName + ".unitypackage";

        // Exports
        AssetDatabase.ExportPackage(paths, fileName, options);
    }
}
```

Now just click the Editor's menu Exports -> Export Project and wait for the process to be complete!

Walla! Now you can save your project as an importable custom package.