# Git checkout freezes and does not change branch

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github

I am working on a git branch in a Unity project. Issue with Unity is that you get loads and loads of files which can be binary and very large. Well, it's game development.

I'd like to merge my branch to the master, which I haven't done for a couple weeks, so I execute as the first step

```
git checkout master
```

Git will never finish this command, I just get a blinking curser below the line. I can see in the GitHub Desktop client that 2100 files are being changed ( this happens in a few minutes) due to the checkout however the branch is never changed. I had it running for 8 hours now and nothing.

I really don't know what I can do now - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could try and clone again repo in a new folder, and then add your previous folder as a remote

```
git clone /url/for/repo/unity unity2
cd unity2
git remote add first_unity ../unity
git fetch fist_unity
git merge first_unity/my_branch
```

Comment: Hi, I'm attempting a clone but it gets stuck as well...oh dear. Any chance I can find out which file is affected?

Comment: What is the url of the repo you are cloning?

Comment: It's a private repo on Visualstudio.com, but I cloned it already a couple times in the past

Comment: Did that repo use git lfs (which VisualStudio.com does support: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/manage-large-files), as recommended in http://stackoverflow.com/q/18225126/6309?

Comment: Nope, we didn't set that up properly. I guess it's too late now for that is it?

Comment: @Axeldabee No you can convert an existing one in order to use LFS: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-bfg-to-migrate-a-repo-to-git-lfs-834233484.html. Then I would suggest to push to a new private repo.