# Fatal Error Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have the following error when openning a Unity project on mac:

```
Fatal Error!
m_PathToGUID.erase(aGood) != 1
```

I did not find any related topic (or answered questions) on unity' website/forum.

How I get this error:

I made a project on Windows (Unity 5.5.1f1)
I zipped the project on put it on a mac (Unity 5.5.0f3)
Get the error.

Remark: I know openning a project with a lower version of unity is not suported, but it worked very well for many weeks until now.

Edit: Only related topic found: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/fata-error-when-openning-project.236669/

Question asked on unity's forum: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/editor-fatal-error-on-openning.458571/

Comment: I strongly recommend you to update you mac Unity. Why do you want to use lower version in first place? You may try to remove Library and Temp folder before opening project.

Comment: Good answer, but rutter's one is more detailed, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message indicates that there is some corruption in your project metadata. This may be the first time that you've encountered a *fatal* error, but over time this sort of thing is bound to accumulate warnings, errors, and inconsistencies. If you're unlucky, you may one day find that your project has suffered a serious data loss -- in extreme cases, you could end up corrupting every scene and prefab in the project.

To avoid that, there are some [best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225126/how-to-use-git-for-unity-source-control) for sharing Unity projects between multiple computers:

1. When possible, use only one consistent version of Unity
2. Switch to `Visible Meta Files` in `Edit → Project Settings → Editor → Version Control Mode`
3. Switch to `Force Text` in `Edit → Project Settings → Editor → Asset Serialization Mode`
4. Avoid copying the `Library` and `Temp` folders between computers; instead, let each computer rebuild those folders using data found in the `meta` files

Addendum to item 4: I often copy/share only the `Assets` and `ProjectSettings` folders from any given project. As long as you're using `meta` files, those two are usually the only folders that you need for Unity to recognize and rebuild a project folder.

Skipping any of these steps can cause you to encounter some very esoteric corner cases in Unity's asset serialization systems.

Ideally you can implement this before starting serious work on a project. If that ship has already sailed, I would recommend applying those steps to the *most stable* copy of your project, which you can then share to other computers.

Comment: Upgrading unity and removing Lybrary folder seems to work, thanks.