# What does your .gitignore file look like for a Unity project?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm starting out with Unity and I've noticed that even with small code changes result in a large git diff.

Originally, my `.gitignore` just had this:

`Temp/`

but it's not doing much heavy lifting.

I found this [.gitignore template](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore)  on Github, but I'm curious if anyone else uses this--either as a starting point or as-is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Git for Unity source control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225126/how-to-use-git-for-unity-source-control)

Comment: https://www.gitignore.io/

Comment: gitignore.io is pretty damn slick!  Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

I use to use that same .gitignore with no issues at all, as-is. Works on both macOS and Windows.

```
/[Ll]ibrary/
/[Tt]emp/
/[Oo]bj/
/[Bb]uild/
/[Bb]uilds/
/Assets/AssetStoreTools*

# Visual Studio 2015 cache directory
/.vs/

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb


# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta

# Unity3D Generated File On Crash Reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
```

Comment: As mentioned in the linked duplicate, the other thing you will want to do is set [Force Text Asset Serialization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luaOL.png) to make assets much more friendly to diff when you do a git check-in.