# Git for unity (and Hololens)

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, hololens

There has been [other questions in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225126/how-to-use-git-for-unity3d-source-control) that explain how to use Git with Unity. I have also found [this resource](http://www.studica.com/blog/how-to-setup-github-with-unity-step-by-step-instructions) dealing with the same problem.

On the other hand there is [this page](http://www.cameronvetter.com/2016/11/02/hololens-tutorial-source-control/) dealing with git for Hololens development (using unity).

My question is more specific. You see in the .gitignore files in the first and second link, they include

```
# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb
```

in the ignore file. Now, in every unity project there is a C# solution file in the root directory (as well as a userprefs file and csproj file).

Why are these files not included for version control??

Ok, you can say "they are not included because when opening a project with unity, they are autogenerated"  (really? is this true?)

But then why in the [ignore file](https://gist.github.com/CameronVetter/99229bd0bb6666bd83f7e27b598dcd94) of the third resource (the one dealing with hololens development) there is no .sln or .userprefs or .csproj included in the ignore file??
(The C# files that are generated by unity are in the App directory which is included so those are not the subject of this question)

Comment: I don't know why its included, but I have a reasonable level of confidence that Unity can regenerate its own solution file if its missing.

Comment: A collection of .gitignore from GitHub : https://github.com/github/gitignore. There is one for Unity. I use it flawlessly for my Hololens projects.

Comment: @RCYR Thanks! Actually that is almost identical at the unity one I am using, but it does not account(ignore) for the App and the UWP folders used for hololens.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer to your question maybe [this](https://gist.github.com/CameronVetter/99229bd0bb6666bd83f7e27b598dcd94) user is not interested to add or he has forget to add those files, as I saw [another gitignore on Github](https://gist.github.com/flarb/95e968a874b166edf75cc0ccfa686d89), it has included .csProject, .userPrefs and .sln and it worked flawlessly accoridng to a user.